# How to backup & restore SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I have a Subversion repository configured in the windows server, having 2000 more revisions. I would like to move it from Windows to Linux, so I want to backup all the revisions & restore to the new svn configuration under linux.

**How do I do that ?**

Comment: Read the SVN (or VisualSVN) manual and do what it says.

Answer (score 8):

I see you've tagged your question with [visualsvn]. Given that you're using the VisualSVN server, you would start the 'VisualSVN Server Manager' application. On the root node in the server tree, right-click and select 'All Tasks->Start Command Prompt'

From the new command prompt, you can dump your repository by issuing:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/your/repo > yourreporname.dump
```

Copy the dump-file to your new server and type:

```
cd /path/to/your/new/repo
svnadmin create reponame
svnadmin load reponame < yourreponame.dump
```

VisualSVN handles access rights on its own, so you'll need to copy the access rights manually.

EDIT:
VisualSVN uses Apache as a front-end server. I guess you could extract the access rights from Apache's configuration files in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to VisualSVN Server 3.6 to use the built-in [scheduled backup and restore](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/backup/) feature. Version 3.6 also adds scheduled repository verification.

> If you look for a one-time backup, you could use
>   [**Backup-SvnRepository**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Backup-SvnRepository) PowerShell cmdlet. To recover the
>   repository, use [**Restore-SvnRepository**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Restore-SvnRepository).